# Router not rendering children

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement authentication checks on my routes. My `App` component is my parent route and I want to render my children within the `App` component.

**Problem:** With my current setup the router never goes in to the `App` component and straight to the `AuthRoutes` if `'/auth'` matches

**Goal:** How can I make sure that if `'/auth'` matches it first goes in to my `App` component where I render its children?

**Index.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Router />
    </ConnectedRouter>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Router.tsx**

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
        <Route path={'/auth'} component={AuthRoutes} />
        <Route component={AuthContainer}>
          <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC = ({ children }: Props<Component>) => {
  return (
    <Layout className="layout">
      <Nav theme={'light'} mode={'horizontal'} />
      <Content style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 24, margin: 0, minHeight: 280 }}>
        {children}
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are using the latest version of react-router (v4) and it seems like you are trying to do nested routes the way previous versions were doing it.

To apply it to your example, you would need to have for:

**App.tsx**

```js
const App: React.FC = ({ children }: Props<Component>) => {
  return (
    <Layout className="layout">
      <Nav theme={'light'} mode={'horizontal'} />
      <Content style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 24, margin: 0, minHeight: 280 }}>
        <Route path={'/auth'} component={AuthRoutes} />
        <Route component={AuthContainer}>
          <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
        </Route>
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Router.tsx**

```js
export default () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={'/'} component={App} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Notice the difference? the nested routes are *inside* `App` component and not children of it.

You can refer to the migration documentation here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#nesting-routes